# displaying multiple rows in single row in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my table, can you please refer 
i am using SQL

**employee table**:

```
emp_id(primary key)  -   emp_name            -  emp_mobile
1                         raju                  123456899
2                         hari                  454654562
3                         aravindth             545485454
4                         siva                  549855291
```

**employeeTechnology** table:

```
emptech_id(primary key)  -  emp_id(foreign key)    -  technology_id(foreign key)
1                            1                               1
2                            1                               2
2                            1                               5
3                            2                               1
4                            2                               3
5                            3                               4
6                            3                               5
7                            4                               3
8                            4                               4
```

**technology** table:

```
technology_id(primary key)  -   tech_name
1                                 java-j2ee
2                                 Dot.net
3                                 DBA-SQL
4                                 big-data
5                                 SAP
```

I want to output like this:

```
emp_id             -    tech_name
1                        java-j2ee/Dot.net/SAP
2                        java-j2ee/DBA-SQL
3                        big-data/SAP
4                        DBA-SQL/big-data
```

I have already tried the following:
`select e.emp_id,t.technology_id from employee e,employeeTechnology et,technology t where e.emp_id =et.emp_id and et.technology_id = t.technology_id`

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: @J. Chomel:i have tried this,,
select e.emp_id,t.technology_id from employee e,employeeTechnology et,technology t where e.emp_id =et.emp_id and et.technology_id = t.technology_id

Comment: Not to me! I know nothing to sql-server, I only know Oracle. You can edit your question :)

Comment: is that the only column to your technology  table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function

```
SELECT
    e.emp_id, STUFF((SELECT '/' + t.tech_name 
     FROM
        dbo.employeeTechnology et 
     INNER JOIN
        dbo.technology t
     ON et.technology_id = t.technology_id
     WHERE
        et.emp_id = e.emp_id
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM
    employee e
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above code but it is not working for me in MySQL.

```
    SELECT  e.emp_id, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT t.`tech_name` ORDER BY `et`.`technology_id` ASC SEPARATOR '/' )  employee_name FROM employee e, employeeTechnology et, technology t  WHERE e.emp_id = et.emp_id AND et.technology_id = t.technology_id  GROUP BY `e`.`emp_id`
```

Now I tried its working fine. I have a question that doesn't MySQL support STUFF function?